# How to speed EDA and model running in r?

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, classification

I am running an exploratory data analysis with SmartEDA package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SmartEDA/SmartEDA.pdf) and one of its functions "ExpReport" allows to create a exploratory data analysis report in HTML format automatically.

I have a dataset with 172 variables and 16487 rows and this is taking so much time to run! Is there a way to speed up R in every tasks we do?

I will also have to run some models with this data (and more data eventually) like randomForest, logistic regression, etc and would like to have a method to do this quickly.

I heard about parallel-processing but can't really understand how it works and if it works only with specific packages or functions...

Thank you all!

This picture shows how memory and cpu are affected just running "ExpReport":
[info about memory and CPU consuption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCaIa.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with large data sets in R is that R reads the entire data set into RAM all at once and R Objects entirely live in memory.

Package `doMC` Provides a parallel backend for the `%dopar%` function using the multicore functionality of the parallel package.

Secondly packages like `Bigmemory`, `ff` & `data.table` come in  real handy.

Here is a vignette that will help you handle large datasets:
https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis

Hope you find this helpful.